# How to Select Multiple Fields from DataGridView using LINQ in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

Technical Details:

- Visual Studio 2017 (Community Edition)
- LINQ
- C# (WinForms)

I'm trying to use LINQ to query the data from a datagridview and display it in another datagridview (the original data source is a text file that is read by the datagridview at runtime). So far, I'm able to do that when selecting one field only.

For example:

- Field 2 = HTTP_CODE
- Field 5 = IP_ADDRESS
- Field 9 = PAGE
- Field 11 = USERNAME

  ```
           //all pages hits report
           var pageCountQuery = (dataGridViewIISDateTime.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
               .Where(r => r.Cells[9].Value != null)
               .Select(r => r.Cells[9].Value)
               .GroupBy(pg => pg)
                   .OrderByDescending(pg => pg.Count())
                   .Select(g => new { PAGE = g.Key, HITS = g.Count() })).ToList();

           dataGridView1.DataSource = pageCountQuery;
  ```

and:

```
                //IPs generating traffic report
                var ipCountQuery = (dataGridViewIISDateTime.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .Where(r => r.Cells[5].Value != null)
                    .Select(r => r.Cells[5].Value)
                    .GroupBy(ip => ip)
                        .OrderByDescending(ip => ip.Count())
                        .Select(g => new { IP_ADDRESS = g.Key, VISITS = g.Count()})).ToList();

                dataGridView1.DataSource = ipCountQuery;
```

But when, I'm trying to select two or three fields using the same code as above, I start getting several warnings about syntax errors, variables being out of scope, etc.

The following is what I'm trying to do (SQL):

An example of selecting two fields:

```
//all pages hits and the IPs hitting them report
select page, ip, count(page)
from [LogFileName]
group by page, ip
order by count(page) desc
```

I tried the following (wrong approach):

```
//var pagesIPCountQuery = (dataGridViewIISDateTime.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    //.Where(r => r.Cells[5].Value != null && r.Cells[9].Value != null)
                    //.Select(r => r.Cells[5].Value, r.Cells[9].Value)
                    //.GroupBy(ip => ip, page => page)
                    //.OrderByDescending(ip => ip.Count(), page => page.Count())
                    //.Select(g => new { IP = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }, { Page = })).ToList();

                    //dataGridView1.DataSource = pagesIPCountQuery;
```

An example of selecting three fields:

```
//500 errors per page and user report
SELECT username, page, http
FROM [LogFileName]
WHERE http = 500
GROUP BY username, page, http
ORDER BY count(http) DESC
```

I tried the following but I get a checkbox on the HTTP_CODE field and it doesn't filter the results by the error 500:

```
var error500Query = (dataGridViewIISDateTime.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                        .Where(r => r.Cells[9].Value != null && r.Cells[2].Value != null && r.Cells[11].Value != null)
                        .Select(r => new { Page = r.Cells[9].Value, HTTP = r.Cells[2].Value.Equals("500"), Username = r.Cells[11].Value })
                        .GroupBy(usernamepagehttp => usernamepagehttp)
                        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                        .Select(g => new { USERNAME = g.Key.Username, PAGE = g.Key.Page, HTTP_CODE = g.Key.HTTP, HITS = g.Count() })).ToList();

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = error500Query;
```

Comment: Show some of your failed attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I can translate this one:

```
//all pages hits and the IPs hitting them report
select page, ip, count(page)
from [LogFileName]
group by page, ip
order by count(page) desc
```

as

```
var pageCountQuery = (dataGridViewIISDateTime.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(r => r.Cells[9].Value != null && r.Cells[5].Value != null)
    .Select(r => new { Page = r.Cells[9].Value, IP = r.Cells[5].Value })
    .GroupBy(pageip => pageip)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .Select(g => new { PAGE = g.Key.Page, IP = g.Key.IP, HITS = g.Count() })).ToList();
```

You haven't said what column HTTP code is in.. But the second SQL you've posted has syntax errors and would only really work in MySQL, and even then only if ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is deactivated

Comment: Hello "Caius Jard." Thank you for your help. I updated my question with the requested information. Your code works pretty well. I tried using a similar approach when using three fields and filtering by the "http error code = 500," but it's not working as intended.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean. If you want to filter you should put *http code = 500* in the Where, not the Select. You f you put it in the select you'll generate a boolean which, if you show it in a DataGridView will cause it to display a checkbox

Comment: Sorry, I'm dumb. I did it wrong. I got it to work by putting "r.Cells[2].Value.Equals("500")" in the "Where" statement. Thank you for your help once again.